# What are my options to deploy Go applications alongside PHP applications?

Tags: apache, nginx, go, fastcgi

What I'm basically trying to accomplish is having my main website running a CMS written in Go. This will be located at www.example.com.

I also have applications written in PHP located in directories, such as www.example.com/clients/

How can I serve example.com/clients using Apache/PHP while serving example.com using Go built-in web server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via `mod_proxy` in Apache2, you can proxy different paths into different destinations at localhost or anywhere else accessible by your server, including within your local network (if your server can access it).

For this you would use `ProxyPass` ([Apache2 Docs for ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass), which is *very* useful reading) like the example below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName some.example.host.xyz

  DocumentRoot /var/www/your-document-root

  Alias /clients/ /var/www/clients/
  ProxyPass /clients/ !
  ScriptAlias /something-using-cgi/ /var/www/cgi-stuff/
  ProxyPass /something-using-cgi/ !

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:9876/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9876/
  ProxyPass /elsewhere/ http://elsewhere.example.host.xyz:1234/
  ProxyPassReverse /elsewhere/ http://elsewhere.example.host.xyz:1234/
</VirtualHost>
```

You'll want to be sure that you set your proxy security such that external users can't use your reverse proxy as a forward proxy, too.  You can do that via `ProxyRequests` as described in the official Apache2 docs.  The way I did this on a server is to put this in your server-wide config (you should verify on your own that this is secure enough):

```
# disables forward proxy
ProxyRequests Off
```

Comment: While Apache is a good example, every popular webserver I know of can do this as well. I'd prefer if you illustrated the concept using Apache as the example. Especially because nginx was also tagged in the post.

Comment: @mvrak: The above is using Apache.  I don't understand what you mean to say.

Comment: Maybe it's semantics, but your answer could be interpreted as something highly specific to Apache rather than a feature that most webservers have, an example of which is the module mod_proxy in Apache.

Comment: My answer _is_ specific to Apache.  The reason I did that is because the actual request was this:  _"How can I serve example.com/clients using Apache/PHP while serving example.com using Go built-in web server?"_  The word "Apache" is specified.  But to do it in nginx would be very different.  There is not standard way to do this, only a standard idea of how to do it, which is not part of the request.

Answer (score 4):

Andrew Gerrand has a good [blog post](http://nf.id.au/deploying-go-web-services-behind-nginx-under) about this for nginx but the principle is the same for Apache.

You want to set up Apache as a reverse proxy for requests coming in for the Go application.
For Apache you want to look at [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html)

Comment: @adamsilver: are you just guessing now, or is there something that actually makes you think that? What about using `<Location /clients/>`? Or `location /clients/ { … };` on nginx?

Comment: You can use `mod_rewrite` alongside `mod_proxy` to do proxied URL filtering so you can push specific paths or directories to different backend destinations, such as your Go-based server or otherwise while keeping other parts of your path within Apache as needed.